# get one collection's data as a sub document Inside another document mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with mongoose. I have a `meta` collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597568f5cf12434674"),
    "data": "test data",
    "createBy" : "testing",
    "modifyBy" : "testing",
    "modifyDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
    "createDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
}
```

this `_id` is in another collection called `orders` as `metaId`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597818bf5332f91213411"),
    "type" : "food order",
    "isActive" : true,
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "metaId" : "597568f5cf12434674",
            "_id" : ObjectId("597818sdfasdaf2222")
        }
    ]
}
```

when I get the order details I need to join the two collections so my final result would be like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597818bf5332f91213411"),
    "type" : "food order",
    "isActive" : true,
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "metaId" : "597568f5cf12434674",
            "data": "test data",
            "createBy" : "testing",
            "modifyBy" : "testing",
            "modifyDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
            "createDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("597818sdfasdaf2222")
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote this query but returns empty, and I know this would be incorrect since I want meta data to be inside of the orders .

```
const query = db.orders.aggregate([  
      {'$match': {'_id': _id}},
      {'$lookup': {
        'localField': 'files.metaId',
        'from': 'meta',
        'foreignField': '_id',
        'as': 'metaInfo'
      }},
      {'$unwind': '$metaInfo'},
      {'$project': {
        'type': 1,
        'isActive': 1,
        'metaInfo.data': 1
      }}
    ]);
```

Is there anyway that I can do this mongo , I am very new to mongodb . please help , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` aggregation operator will not work with an array on the 'from' side so you have to unwind it first:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([  
  // matches a single document in the orders collection
  {'$match': {'_id': ObjectId("59784eb56149554af36a5666")}},

  // unwinds orders.files so that it is no longer an array
  {'$unwind': '$files'},

  // performs the lookup on the meta collection and assigns the 'looked up' sub document to the attribute: "files"
  {'$lookup': {
    'localField': 'files.metaId',
    'from': 'meta',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'files'
  }}
]);
```

The above command will return the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59784eb56149554af36a5666"),
    "type" : "food order",
    "isActive" : true,
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59784e706149554af36a5621"),
            "data" : "test data",
            "createBy" : "testing",
            "modifyBy" : "testing",
            "modifyDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
            "createDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: this populates the files attribute with the content document which was 'looked up' from the meta collection so you lose the `files.metaId` though since the join was made from `orders.files.metaId` to `meta._id` the value of _id in the files sub document **is the same as** `orders.files.metaId`. You can see this if you change the command slightly:

```
  db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([  
    // matches a single document in the orders collection
    {'$match': {'_id': ObjectId("59784eb56149554af36a5666")}},

    // unwinds orders.files so that it is no longer an array
    {'$unwind': '$files'},

    // performs the lookup on the meta collection and assigns the 'looked up' sub document to the attribute: "files"
    {'$lookup': {
      'localField': 'files.metaId',
      'from': 'meta',
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'metaData'
    }}
  ]);
```

This returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59784eb56149554af36a5666"),
    "type" : "food order",
    "isActive" : true,
    "files" : {
        "metaId" : ObjectId("59784e706149554af36a5621")
    },
    "metaData" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59784e706149554af36a5621"),
            "data" : "test data",
            "createBy" : "testing",
            "modifyBy" : "testing",
            "modifyDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z"),
            "createDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T03:26:45.350Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

In which `files.metaId == metaData._id`.

Comment: this is working , great :). thank you very much . but one thing can we keep ""metaId"" value instead of removing it and also I need to keep the old _id field

Comment: I've updated the answer to address this point: `can we keep ""metaId"" value instead of removing it`. I'm not clear on this requirement though: `I need to keep the old _id field`.